# Cannot find functions as part of classes Godot

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I have just started learning Godot and already know a decent bit of C# from unity. I am trying to set up a 3D character rig. The function should be there as the docs all say it should but when I compile this code:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class world_control : Node
{
    SceneTree tree;
    Node3D camera;
    Node3D head;
    
    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        tree = GetTree();
        camera = tree.get_current_scene().find_child("camera", false, false);
        head = tree.get_current_scene().find_child("head", true, false);
    }

    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
        camera.set_global_position(head.get_global_position());
        camera.set_global_rotation(head.get_global_rotation());
    }
}
```

It gives me these errors:

```
/***/Godot/Hand_Cannon/world_control.cs(14,17): 'SceneTree' does not contain a definition for 'get_current_scene' and no accessible extension method 'get_current_scene' accepting a first argument of type 'SceneTree' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

/***/Godot/Hand_Cannon/world_control.cs(21,35): 'Node3D' does not contain a definition for 'get_global_position' and no accessible extension method 'get_global_position' accepting a first argument of type 'Node3D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

(I have left out a few more errors but basically all of the functions cause this excact error)

Extra Information:
Godot 4.1 with C#
.NET 8 (Installed on day of posting)
Mac OSX 13.5.1

I can and am very willing to provide more info if needed!

This is a problem in which I simply don't know what to try. I am very new to Godot having installing it today. Nothing so far has worked, in fact I did not even know that the values had getter functions!

Comment: What leads you to think that SceneTree supports a `get_current_scene` method?

Comment: @TimRoberts The documentation: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-property-current-scene

Comment: That documentation is from 2014.  Can you treat it as a property?  As in `camera = tree.current_scene.find_child...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# methods and properties in Godot use PascalCase, while GDScript methods use snake_case. Global methods in C#, such as Print, can be accessed through the GD static class. Apart from that, you can try the code below for your use case:

```
// Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{
    SceneTree tree = GetTree();
    camera = (Node3D)tree.CurrentScene.GetNode("camera", false, false);
    head = (Node3D)tree.CurrentScene.GetNode("head", true, false);
}

// Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
public override void _Process(double delta)
{
    camera.Position = head.Position;
    camera.Rotation = head.Rotation;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely test this out when I get the time.

Comment: I had to make two changes to get this to work: changing Root to CurrentScene and changing FindChild to GetNode. Otherwise it works! Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: I will edit the answer according to your update to help other people. To be fair, I am also new to Godot. Additionally, I'm using it with the C# language as I want to improve my C# skills along with game development skills.

I'm glad I could help.